# Visualisation with Python

Tags: python, image, visualization

I want to plot the data from a connected device (which count number of steps) used by 100 users. I got about 4000 records for each user.

So I plot each point mannualy in a picture of size 100*4000 using the package PIL : `Image.putpixel((CurrentTimePx,CurrentRowPx),(CurrentActivityPixelIntensity,0,0))`

But the picture is too small, I have to zoom to see correctly the points.

Do you have a solution to print the picture point by point but with a correct size ?

Edit :

It's a bit more difficult : for one user, I plot a point (at time 0) for which intensity=number of steps. Then I skip to next row (for another user) and I do the same. Once I've done all the users, I skip to next column (for time 1) and so on...

I join a picture of the complete visualisation. [Final Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqnDA.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try using matplotlib instead of PIL.

Matplotlib:

http://matplotlib.org/

Specifically about bar charts (I think this is what you want):

http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Answer (score 1):

I would put these data in a (100, 4000) numpy array and plot it using `matplotlib`. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# TODO: Put data in numpy array X
# TODO: Define the image size you want in my_size (eg, my_size=(10, 20))
plt.figure(figsize=my_size)
plt.imshow(X, interpolation="nearest", aspect="auto")
plt.savefig("my_plot.pdf")
```